# Why did Tor quit opening? I deleted, reinstalled, still won't open

Tags: mac, connection

I'm on a Mac OS. I installed Tor about a year ago. Today it went down. When I asked for a bridge, I copied it, but missed part. I tried all suggestions, finally deleted and reinstalled. Install was a success, but still won't open.

Comment: Can you please provide more details like an error message and/or screenshot? It's too wide to be an answerable question

Comment: Sorry. No error message. Just the "Establishing connection" starting that hangs. Clipboard- "delaying directory fetches:no running bridges". Previous clipboard notice was I evidently didn't copy the entire bridge info and it had to be scrubbed

Comment: so I think that it's solved and working now?

Comment: Yeah, I think there needs to be more details for us to understand how exactly to solve the issue.